# Number of arrangements in a rectangular table (II)

Tags: combinatorics

18 diplomats sit on a rectangular table. Three are from China, four are from Japan, six are from the United States and five are from France. In how many ways can we seat the diplomats at the table so that both the Chinese and the Japanese stay together, but separated from each other?

I thought I had this sorted out, but no.
My proposed solution was the following:

First I allocated the 11 diplomats (US + France) that can sit without restrictions: $$ 11! $$
Then I count the number of places between these diplomats in which the Chinese or the Japanese groups can sit: $$ 11 $$ , since that this is a closed arrangement, the 'last' diplomat is next to the 'first' one.
Then I started by allocating the Chinese group. The Chinese group can stay in 11 places between the $$ 11 $$ diplomats and they can be arranged in $$ 3! $$ ways within themselves: $$ 11 * 3! $$
After the Chinese are seated, we have $$ 10 $$ places left between the diplomats where the Japanese can sit; the Japanese diplomats can be arranged in $$ 4! $$ ways amongst themselves: $$ 10 * 4! $$ .

Lastly, we have to consider the symmetry of the rectangle, meaning that we have been counting these arrangements twice, as the sides of the rectangle are equal two-by-two.

So in my mind we should have in total $$ \frac{11! * 11* 3! * 10 * 4!}{2} = 316 141 056 000 $$ .
However, the number of ways is supposed to be $$ 379 369 267 200 $$ . Can you please help me find what is wrong in my thinking?

Thank you.

Comment: Together means on the same side of the table too?

Comment: Together means being next to each other, side by side. They can even around the same corner, for instance.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673665) may help you.

Comment: Thank you @Doubtnut, but unfortunately it doesn't. The problem is not the same because here we are distributing all the people in the rectangle and not only one side of it...

Comment: How do you know what the number of ways "is supposed to be"?

Comment: How sure are you of the supposed solution?

Comment: Please address the comments, Bruno.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I took this problem from the book which gives this number as the final solution, so I am supposing that is the correct solution.

Comment: Well, Bruno, maybe it isn't. Books can have mistakes. Try doing the problem again, but with smaller numbers, numbers small enough that you can write down and count all the arrangements, and see whether your reasoning gives the right answer.

Comment: It's interesting that the answer you came up with is exactly 5/6 of the purported correct answer.

Comment: I have redone this with smaller numbers and I have realized that I did not rotate the diplomats along the seats on the table. But with this rationale, the number I had got would have been multiplied by 18/2 = 9 ...

Comment: @BrunoCAfonso; but rotating the diplomats creates repeats, because ABCD rotated is the same as BCDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found the supposed solution. Firstly a rectangular table is not a round table. I suppose all diplomats should sit at the same side, so the table is a line. Secondly if we reverse the order we should count it as the same arrangement. (I. e. two arrangements are distinct if at least one diplomat has different set of neighbors.)

Let's consider Chinese delegation as a single metadiplomat and the same for Japanese delegation. Then we have $13$ diplomats, $2$ of which can't sit together. There are $13!$ arrangements in total and $2 \cdot 12!$ of them contain Chinese and Japanese metadiplomats next to each other. So we have $13! - 2 \cdot 12!$ arrangements.

Now remember that Chinese delegation can sit in $3!$ ways and Japanese delegation can sit in $4!$ ways within their places. And reversing order gives the same arrangements. Then we have

$$\frac{(13! - 2 \cdot 12!) \cdot 3! \cdot 4!}{2} = 379369267200$$

arrangements.

**P. S.** For a round table under the same assumption about distinct arrangements we start with Chinese metadiplomat, have $10$ (of $12$) places for Japanese metadiplomat and $11!$ ways to arrange other diplomats. Taking into account possible reverse of order we get

$$\frac{10 \cdot 11! \cdot 3! \cdot 4!}{2} = 28740096000$$

arrangements, that is $11$ times less than you answer.

If two arrangements are distinct if at least one diplomat has another seat then we should not divide by $2$, but should multiply by $18$ possible options for the leftmost diplomat of Chinese delegation and get
$$10 \cdot 11! \cdot 3! \cdot 4! \cdot 18 = 1034643456000$$
arrangements.

In your reasoning you don't have $11$ places for $11$ diplomats, so you should count only $10!$ cyclic orders, but not $11!$. Then you will get $28740096000$.

Comment: this is great, thank you! Just one thing: in your circular example, I understood the solution when you start with a Chinese / Japanese metadiplomat. But the solution should be the same if you start by putting the 11 diplomats. Why do you divide by 11 (cyclic orders) there and whereas you do not divide by 3 when you start by putting the Chinese? The logic does not seem to be the same.

Comment: @BrunoCAfonso I can start not with metadiplomat, but with one of $3$ Chinese diplomats, who will be the leftmost one. After that I will add two more Chinese diplomats in $3 \cdot 2!$ in total. When I fix the position of Chinese metadiplomat it is essentially the same as divide the total number $13! - 2 \cdot 12! - 2 \cdot 11! = 13! - 2 \cdot 13 \cdot 11! = 13 \cdot (12 - 2) \cdot 11! = 13 \cdot 10 \cdot 11!$ of good permutations by the number $13$ of elements to get the number of good cyclic orders.

Comment: I just did not understand why don't we recover the same result and apply the same logic to the metadiplomat, because, as you said and I agree, it brings different results.

Comment: @BrunoCAfonso Sorry, I don't clearly understand your question. If you mean your initial solution, then the problem is that you start from a table with 11 seats, assign a seat to each diplomat and after that you bring additional chairs for Chinese and Japanese diplomats. However initially you could shift 11 diplomats and get the same assignment. Two my methods give the same result and if needed I will add more details

Answer (score 2):

**NEW**

I've noticed we could have $J$ at one end, and $C$ at the other, which is also an illegal arrangement.

So I tried this instead, which gives an answer of $465,589,555,200$, but seems logically sound.

Label the chairs $1\dots18$. Note that starting from $1$ is the same as starting from $10$. First place the Chinese trio ($18$ ways times $6$ for internal positions), and then the Japanese ($9\times24$), and then the $11$ remaining diplomats ($11!$), and divide by $2$:

$$\frac{18\cdot6\cdot9\cdot24\cdot11!}{2}=465,589,555,200$$

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I get the correct answer like this:

We have $13$ entities:

- 6 USA
- 5 French
- 1 Chinese conglomerate of $3$
- 1 Japanese conglomerate of $4$

There are $13!$ ways to arrange these, but then there is the additional rule that we cannot have either $JC$ or $CJ$.

There are $12\cdot11!$ permutations with $JC$ in them, and the same with $CJ$ in them, so the total number of permutations is $13!-2\cdot12!=(13-2)\cdot12!=11\cdot12!=5,269,017,600$.

Next multiply by $3!\cdot4!=144$ for the inner positioning of the Chinese and Japanese, and then a rectangular table has one line of symmetry, so divide by $2$, which gives $379,369,267,200$.

Comment: thank you, very good! I had interpreted the problem as if the table was a rectangle but the diplomats were sitting around it and not on a line, now I see!